# In Chrome console is breakpoints pause before or after execution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

In the Chrome console if I go sources > event listener breakpoints > click > mouse click and then activate breakpoints.

Now if I click on an e.g. `<a>` element Chrome creates an overlay and shows me a script that fired, or is going to fire, before I click "resume script execution"

My question is Chrome showing me what just got executed or what is going to be executed when I click resume?

Comment: test it yourself! attach a `console.log('hi');` to a click event

Comment: Thanks for the tip which sounds really obvious but I'm not in JS everyday and use it only occasionally. I tried your suggestion and it looks like you are shown what is ABOUT to fire, not what HAS fired. Did I get that right? I was shown the index file for the whole page, and since I just added onlick= to an <a> presumed that's why I was shown the whole doc. Then "hi" appeared in console AFTER I clicked again